# Problems w/ callback function over integers of a LinkedList nested within another LinkedList in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm having trouble iterating and applying a callback function over integers of a LinkedList nested within another LinkedList. Calling `board.forEach(printBoard);`, I do not get the expected output of `76543217654321` and instead, I get no input. I'm having a hard time figuring out the problem since `A.forEach(printByte);` does return `7654321`. If you have any idea what's wrong with my code, please let me know. Thanks.

```
template <class T> 
class LinkedList {
  struct Node {
      T x;
      Node *next;
  };
  private:
    Node *head;
  public:
    LinkedList(){
        head = NULL;
    }

    ~LinkedList(){
        Node *next = head;

        while(next) {  
            Node *deleteMe = next;
            next = next->next;
            delete deleteMe;
        }
    }

    // prepend a new value to the beginning of the list
    void add(T val){
        Node *n = new Node();
        n->x = val;
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }

    void forEach(void (*callback)(T)) {
      Node *n = head;
      while (n != NULL) {
        (*callback)(n->x);
        n = n->next;
      }
    }
};

void printInt(int x) {
  Serial.print(x);
}

void printBoard(LinkedList<int> x) {
  x.forEach(printInt);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 

  LinkedList<int> A;
  A.add(1);
  A.add(2);
  A.add(3);
  A.add(4);
  A.add(5);
  A.add(6);
  A.add(7);
  A.forEach(printInt); // returns 7654321

  LinkedList<LinkedList<int>> board;
  board.add(A);
  board.add(A);
  board.forEach(printBoard); // returns nothing
}
```

Comment: If you're using C++ then you should use `std::function` instead of raw function-pointers.

Comment: Put a breakpoint or print statement in LinkedList's destructor. The result may surprise you.

Comment: @Dai I forgot to mention it but I'm using Arduino which does not natively offer `std::function`.

Comment: @DanielWaechter Thanks, my problem was caused by the deconstructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code has some the memory problems. The node's address(pointer) is duplicated (double free problem). If you want to copy the structure, it needs new memory allocation and readdressing of the nodes for linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

template <class T> 
class LinkedList {
  struct Node {
      T *x;
      Node *next;
  };
  private:
    Node *head;
  public:
    LinkedList(){
        printf("constructor:%p\n", this) ;
        head = NULL;
    }

    ~LinkedList(){
        printf("destructor:%p\n", this) ;
        Node *next = head;
        while(next) {  
            Node *deleteMe = next;
            next = next->next;
            printf("delete node:%p\n", deleteMe) ;
            delete deleteMe->x ;    // x
            delete deleteMe;
        }
    }

    LinkedList* Dup() {
        LinkedList *newList = new LinkedList<T>() ;
        Node *n = head ;
        while (n != NULL) {
            T *newx = new T(); 
            *newx=*(n->x) ;
//          newList->addTail(n->x) ;
            newList->addTail(newx) ;
            n = n->next;
        }
        return newList ;
    }

    // prepend a new value to the beginning of the list
    // val : caller must allocate memory.
    void add(T *val){
        Node *n = new Node();
        printf(" addhead: new alloc node %p\n", n) ;
//      T *newval = new T();
//      *newval = *val ;
//        n->x = newval;
        n->x = val ;
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }

    // add to end
    // val : caller must allocate memory.
    void addTail(T *val) {
        Node *n = new Node();
        Node *l = head ;

        printf(" addtail: new alloc node %p\n", n) ;
//      T *newval = new T();
//      *newval = *val ;
//        n->x = newval;
        n->x = val ;
        n->next = NULL ;
        if ( l==NULL ) {
            head = n ;
            return ;
        }
        while(l->next!=NULL) {
            l = l->next ;
        }
        l->next = n ;
    }

    void forEach(void (*callback)(T*)) {
      Node *n = head;
      while (n != NULL) {
        (*callback)(n->x);
        n = n->next;
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
};

void printInt(int *x) {
//  Serial.print(x);
    printf("%d ", *x) ;
}

void printBoard(LinkedList<int> *x) {
  x->forEach(printInt);
}

int main() {
  //Serial.begin(9600); 

  printf("make A\n") ;
  int avail_Afree=0 ;

#if 0
    // use stack memory
  LinkedList<int> A;
  LinkedList<int> *pA=&A;
#else
    // use heap
  LinkedList<int> *pA = new LinkedList<int>();
  avail_Afree=1 ;
#endif
  int val=0 ;

  for (int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
    printf("add node:%d\n", i) ;
//    val=i ;
    int *pval = new int() ;
    *pval = i ;
//    pA->add(&val);
    pA->add(pval);
  }
  pA->forEach(printInt);


    // prepare copied data.
  LinkedList<int> *pA2, *pA3 ;
printf("make A2\n") ;
  pA2 = pA->Dup() ;
  pA2->forEach(printInt) ;

printf("make A3\n") ;
  pA3 = pA->Dup() ;
  pA3->forEach(printInt) ;


    // make board
  LinkedList<LinkedList<int> > *pBoard;
  printf("make Board\n") ;
  pBoard = new LinkedList<LinkedList<int> > () ;

    printf("  Board add: A2\n") ;
  pBoard->add(pA2);

    printf("  Board add: A3\n") ;
  pBoard->add(pA3);

    printf(" print Board\n") ;
  pBoard->forEach(printBoard); // returns nothing

  if ( avail_Afree ) {
    printf("delete pA:%p\n", pA) ;
    delete pA ;
  }

/* 
  printf("delete pA2:%p\n", pA2) ;
  delete pA2 ;
  printf("delete pA3:%p\n", pA3) ;
  delete pA3 ;
  // pBoard will free A2,A3.
*/
  printf("delete pBoard:%p\n", pBoard) ;
  delete pBoard ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

output is this

```
make A
constructor:0x7fb8f8d00000
add node:1
 addhead: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00020
add node:2
 addhead: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00040
add node:3
 addhead: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00060
add node:4
 addhead: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00080
add node:5
 addhead: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d000a0
add node:6
 addhead: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d000c0
add node:7
 addhead: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d000e0
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
make A2
constructor:0x7fb8f8d000f0
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00110
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00130
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00150
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00170
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00190
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d001b0
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d001d0
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
make A3
constructor:0x7fb8f8d001e0
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00200
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00220
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00240
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00260
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d00280
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d002a0
 addtail: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d002c0
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
make Board
constructor:0x7fb8f8d002d0
  Board add: A2
 addhead: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d002e0
  Board add: A3
 addhead: new alloc node 0x7fb8f8d002f0
 print Board
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 

delete pA:0x7fb8f8d00000
destructor:0x7fb8f8d00000
delete node:0x7fb8f8d000e0
delete node:0x7fb8f8d000c0
delete node:0x7fb8f8d000a0
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00080
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00060
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00040
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00020
delete pBoard:0x7fb8f8d002d0
destructor:0x7fb8f8d002d0
delete node:0x7fb8f8d002f0
destructor:0x7fb8f8d001e0
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00200
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00220
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00240
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00260
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00280
delete node:0x7fb8f8d002a0
delete node:0x7fb8f8d002c0
delete node:0x7fb8f8d002e0
destructor:0x7fb8f8d000f0
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00110
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00130
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00150
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00170
delete node:0x7fb8f8d00190
delete node:0x7fb8f8d001b0
delete node:0x7fb8f8d001d0
```